# Firefox/Chrome opening a file send dirrectly to printer

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, printing

Is it possible to make Firefox or Chrome browsers open print dialog box when opening a specific file (extension)? I have a system which I access using internet browser and it produces .ODT/.PDF reports which I'd like to send directly to a printer instead of Downloading/Opening/Printing steps. Unfortunately can't use any javascript on the server side (although client side scripting is possible). It's also possible to change file extension of those reports to anything I want.

Answer (score 1):

I've researched this quite a bit and there doesn't seem to be a simple way to do it.

An [NPAPI plugin](https://code.google.com/p/firebreath/) (such as one created with "Firebreath") could do this, but would need to be compiled for each platform it runs on (similar to loading Flash as a browser plugin).  You would have to build this plugin from scratch.  Getting this plugin to list in the Google Play Store is the only way Chrome users can install it, which is a $25 registration fee, and a code review by Google (since it uses NPAPI).  Note that Firebreath also creates an ActiveX plugin which can be used in Internet Explorer.

If you're willing to use Java, there is a project called "[jZebra](https://code.google.com/p/jzebra/)" which has very limited [PDF printing capabilities](https://code.google.com/p/jzebra/wiki/TutorialWebApplet#PDF_Printing) from the web browser, but it requires a Java Applet to be loaded.

-Tres